# How to navigate between pages inside Frame with a NavigationMenu

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a project with 3 different pages to be eventually loaded within a Frame. In Frame1 how can I use a click event to navigate to a different page inside the Frame (i.e. Frame 3)?

**XAML**

```
<NavigationView Name="NavView">
    <Frame Name="myFrame"/>
</NavigationView>
```

**XAML.CS**

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        myFrame.Navigate(typeof(Frame1));
    }
```

**Frame1.xaml**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Text="Frame 1" FontSize="36"/>
    <Button Name="Button1" Text="Frame 3"/>
</Grid>
```

**Frame2.xaml**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Text="Frame 2" FontSize="36"/>
</Grid>
```

**Frame3.xaml**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Text="Frame 3" FontSize="36"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Frame1 how can I use a click event to navigate to a different page inside the Frame (i.e. Frame 3)?

**Frame1.xaml**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Text="Frame 1" FontSize="36"/>
    <Button Name="Button1" Text="Frame 3"/>
</Grid>
```

You could add the `Click` event handler for Button then process the navigation in the code behind. If  you want to navigate to Frame3 **page** from Frame1 page , you could use Frame1 page `Frame` property to navigate.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Frame3));
}
```